# Перестал работать плагин Google reCAPTCHA

Tags: битрикс, captcha

После обновления версии PHP с 7.4 на 8.1 Битрикс ругается и выдает ошибку

```
[TypeError] 
call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, non-static method B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha::initCheckSpam() cannot be called statically (0)
```

Пробовал добавлять static к function но не помогает. Код класса:

```
class BitrixCaptcha
{
    /**
     * Подключаем JS скрипты для reCaptcha v3
     */
    public function initJS()
    {
        $Asset = Asset::getInstance();
        $siteKey = Option::get(M::id(), 'site_key_'. SITE_ID);
        $hideBadge = Option::get(M::id(), 'hide_badge_'. SITE_ID, 'Y');

        if (empty($siteKey)) return true;

        $Asset->addString('<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render='. $siteKey .'"></script>');
        $Asset->addString('<script>window.recaptcha = { siteKey: "'. $siteKey .'", tokenLifeTime: 100 };</script>'); // время жизни токена в секундах (2 минуты максимальное время жизни токена)
        $Asset->addString('<script src="/bitrix/js/b01110011.recaptcha/script.js"></script>');
        
        if ($hideBadge == 'Y')
            $Asset->addString('<style>.grecaptcha-badge {display: none;}</style>');
    }

    /**
     * Подключаем проверку на спам
     */
    public function initCheckSpam()
    {
        $secretKey = Option::get(M::id(), 'secret_key_'. SITE_ID);
        if (empty($secretKey)) return true;

        $EventManager = EventManager::getInstance();

        $EventManager->addEventHandler('form', 'onBeforeResultAdd', ['B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha', 'checkWebForm']);
        $EventManager->addEventHandler('main', 'OnBeforeUserRegister', ['B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha', 'checkRegistration']);
        $EventManager->addEventHandler('main', 'OnBeforeEventAdd', ['B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha', 'checkFeedback']);
        $EventManager->addEventHandler('iblock', 'OnBeforeIBlockElementAdd', ['B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha', 'checkIBlock']);
        $EventManager->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnBeforeOrderAdd', ['B01110011ReCaptcha\BitrixCaptcha', 'checkSaleOrder']);
    }

    /**
     * Проверка форм из модуля веб форм
     */
    public function checkWebForm($WEB_FORM_ID, &$arFields, &$arValues)
    {
        if ($arFields['RECAPTCHA_DISABLE']) return true;

        $webformIDs = Option::get(M::id(), 'webform_ids_'. SITE_ID);
        if (empty($webformIDs)) return true;

        // если не из списка проверяемых форм пришли данные, то не проверяем капчу
        $webformIDs = explode(',', $webformIDs);
        if (!in_array($WEB_FORM_ID, $webformIDs, true)) return true;
        
        return self::checkSpam();
    }

    /**
     * Проверка при регистрации пользователя
     */
    public function checkRegistration(&$arArgs)
    {
        $registrationEnable = Option::get(M::id(), 'registration_enable_'. SITE_ID, 'N');
        if ($registrationEnable == 'N') return true;

        return self::checkSpam();
    }

    /**
     * Проверка при оформлении заказа
     */
    public function checkSaleOrder(&$arFields)
    {
        if ($arFields['RECAPTCHA_DISABLE']) return true;

        $saleOrderEnable = Option::get(M::id(), 'sale_order_enable_'. SITE_ID, 'N');
        if ($saleOrderEnable == 'N') return true;

        return self::checkSpam();
    }

    /**
     * Проверка при отправки формы обратной связи main.feedback
     */
    public function checkFeedback(&$event, &$lid, &$arFields, &$messageId, &$files, &$languageId)
    {
        if ($arFields['RECAPTCHA_DISABLE']) return true;

        $feedbackIDs = Option::get(M::id(), 'main_feedback_ids_'. SITE_ID);
        if (empty($feedbackIDs)) return true;

        // если не из списка проверяемых форм пришли данные, то не проверяем капчу
        $feedbackIDs = explode(',', $feedbackIDs);
        if (!in_array((string) $messageId, $feedbackIDs, true)) return true;
        
        return self::checkSpam();
    }

    /**
     * Проверка при добавлении в инфоблок
     */
    public function checkIBlock(&$arParams)
    {
        if ($arParams['RECAPTCHA_DISABLE']) return true;

        $iblockIDs = Option::get(M::id(), 'iblock_ids_'. SITE_ID);
        if (empty($iblockIDs)) return true;

        // если не из списка проверяемых инфоблоков пришли данные, то не проверяем капчу
        $iblockIDs = explode(',', $iblockIDs);
        if (!in_array((string) $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], $iblockIDs, true)) return true;
        
        return self::checkSpam();
    }

    /**
     * Основной метод проверки капчи
     */
    public function checkSpam()
    {
        global $APPLICATION;

        // если мы добавляем данные из админки, то не проверяем
        if (preg_match('/^\/bitrix\/admin\/.*$/i', $APPLICATION->GetCurPage())) return true;

        $isError = false;
        $recaptcha_token = $_REQUEST['recaptcha_token'];

        if (isset($recaptcha_token) && !empty($recaptcha_token))
        {
            $secretKey = Option::get(M::id(), 'secret_key_'. SITE_ID);
            $permissibleScore = (float) Option::get(M::id(), 'permissible_score_'. SITE_ID, 0.5);

            $recaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secretKey, $permissibleScore);
            $response = $recaptcha->verify($recaptcha_token);

            if (!$response['isSuccess']) $isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $isError = true;
        }

        if ($isError)
        {
            $errorMessage = Option::get(M::id(), 'error_message_'. SITE_ID);
            if (empty($errorMessage)) $errorMessage = Loc::getMessage(M::locPrefix() .'CAPTCHA_ERROR_MESSAGE');

            $APPLICATION->ThrowException($errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php 8 добавлена проверка статического вызова методов и теперь если вы вызываете *BitrixCaptcha::initCheckSpam();*, то получаете ошибку.

Для исправления необходимо использовать вызов

```
(new BitrixCaptcha)->initCheckSpam();
```

или помечать метод как static:

```
public static function initCheckSpam()
```

Статический метод это метод, который вызывается без экземпляра класса, для примера для обработки событий нам не нужен объект, а значит мы можем делать методы статическими.